# How To Achieve Python3.4 Virtualenv For Precise64 VirtualBox

Tags: django, virtual-machine, ubuntu-12.04, ansible, python-3.4

I'm trying to create virtualbox using precise64, Vagrant, and Ansible.  I am able to get python2.7 virtualenv setup, but would like to use python3.4 instead.  I cloned the [ansible-django-stack](https://github.com/jcalazan/ansible-django-stack) repository and everything works, but it is using version 2.7.  What should I change in order to get a python3.4 Virtualenv up and running?

This question might seem like I'm being lazy and just want someone to do it for me, but I have been searching for two days trying to get this working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit this two file

[System packages](https://github.com/jcalazan/ansible-django-stack/blob/master/roles/base/tasks/main.yml)

After line26 add

```
- python3-dev
- python3-setuptools
```

to get python3-dev and python3-setuptools packages.

[Virtualenv](https://github.com/jcalazan/ansible-django-stack/blob/master/roles/web/tasks/setup_virtualenv.yml)

Replace 4th line with `command: virtualenv {{ virtualenv_path }} --no-site-packages -p /usr/bin/python3` to instruct virtualenv to use python3

Please note [youtube-audio-dl](https://github.com/jcalazan/youtube-audio-dl) is not compatible with python3. You may use any other python3 compatible app or make required changes to make it python3 compatible.

To get started with Ansible --  [Ansible - Getting Started](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_getting_started.html)

Comment: What should I put in order to install python 3.4?  I see no examples online doing this and the documentation doesn't reference anything that helps with installing a different version of python.